# Is gone the Handles of Curve tools in 2.8 version?

Tags: bezier-curves

I can't find Handles tool of Curves in Blender 2.8, Indeed, has it gone?

[image]

Comment: "Control points/set handle type" menu (or V).

Comment: Thank you V works!

Comment: Maybe you know also where is it in Blender interface? Thanks advance

Comment: In the menu (top bar of 3D View)

Answer (score 1):

I have found, it is in the Control Points menu
[image]